# gluPerspective was removed in OpenGL 3.1, any replacements?

Tags: c++, deprecated, opengl-3, freeglut

I'm trying to read some OpenGL tutorials on the net. the problem is that I found some old ones that use `gluPerspective()`. gluPerspective was deprecated in OpenGL 3.0 and removed in 3.1.

What function can I use instead?

I'm using C++ with latest FreeGlut installed.

Comment: I know it's pedantic, but gluPerspective has never been part of OpenGL (hence the glu prefix). glFrustum was, and has been deprecated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to compute the matrix manually and then pass it to OpenGL.

### Computing the matrix

This snippet of code is based on the [gluPerspective documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).

```
 void BuildPerspProjMat(float *m, float fov, float aspect,
 float znear, float zfar)
 {
  float f = 1/tan(fov * PI_OVER_360);

  m[0]  = f/aspect;
  m[1]  = 0;
  m[2]  = 0;
  m[3]  = 0;

  m[4]  = 0;
  m[5]  = f;
  m[6]  = 0;
  m[7]  = 0;

  m[8]  = 0;
  m[9]  = 0;
  m[10] = (zfar + znear) / (znear - zfar);
  m[11] = -1;

  m[12] = 0;
  m[13] = 0;
  m[14] = 2*zfar*znear / (znear - zfar);
  m[15] = 0;
 }
```

There is a C++ library called [OpenGL Mathematics](http://glm.g-truc.net/) that may be useful.

### Loading the Matrix in OpenGL 3.1

I am still new to the OpenGL 3.1 API, but you need to update a matrix on the GPU and then make use of it in your vertex shader to get the proper perspective. The following code just loads the matrix using [glUniformMatrix4fv](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) onto the video card.

```
{
  glUseProgram(shaderId);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderId, "u_proj_matrix"),
                     1, GL_FALSE, theProjectionMatrix);
  RenderObject();
  glUseProgram(0);
}
```

A simple vertex shader from a random [blog](http://blog.mgrundmann.com/?p=4) (found through stack overflow).

```
attribute vec4      a_position;
attribute vec4      a_color;

varying vec4        v_color;

uniform mat4 u_proj_matrix;
uniform mat4 u_model_matrix;

void main() {
  mat4 mvp_matrix = u_proj_matrix * u_model_matrix;
  v_color = a_color;
  gl_Position = mvp_matrix * a_position;
}
```

Comment: thank you :) that opengl mathematics library seems not bad at all.

Comment: This function doesn't work. What is xmax and ymax? They're used on the second line and not defined

Comment: I followed the article sources back to the original, which is in French: http://www.xgouchet.fr/blog/index.php/post/2009/07/27/Definir-le-zoom-du-Camera-sous-OpenGL-ES. It sets ymax = znear * tan(fov * PI_OVER_360); and gets via xmax = ymax * aspect. ymin = -ymax; xmin = ymin * aspect;

Comment: I worked through the maths for gluPerspective and glFrustum. It may be neater to write width = xmax-xmin and height = ymax-ymin; following which the line w = w/aspect will not be required.

Comment: I want to add, that as koan states, `w = w/aspect` MUST be removed from the computation as it stands now for the matrix to work correctly. I used this matrix myself and couldn't figure out why the aspect was wrong whenever I used anything other than 1 as aspect. Also `width = xymax - xmin` should be `width = xmax - xmin`, and `height = xymax - ymin` should be `height = ymax - ymin`.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that "fov" is the *vertical* fov.  It's easy to accidentally specify the horizontal fov, as that's typically what games speak in terms of.

Comment: Could someone who has tested this please edit the appropriate changes instead of making a large change log in the comments.

Answer (score 11):

Use [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/index.html).

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(
  // FOV & aspect
  60.0f, 16.0f / 10.0f, 
  // Near and far planes
  0.001f, 1000f);

// If you're using the now deprecated matrix stacks
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(projection));

// if you're using the new shader based pipelines
GLint projectionUniformLocation = ...;
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, 
  glm::value_ptr(projection));
```

Note, if you have `GLM_FORCE_RADIANS` defined then you should use radians in the perspective function, not degrees...

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(
  // FOV & aspect
  PI / 3.0f, 16.0f / 10.0f, 
  // Near and far planes
  0.001f, 1000f);
```

Comment: Note that starting from GLM 0.9.6.0, `GLM_FORCE_RADIANS` is no longer need nor supported, since GLM now works only with radians.

Answer (score 9):

Copied from one of my older projects:

```
// The following code is a fancy bit of math that is eqivilant to calling:
// gluPerspective( fieldOfView/2.0f, width/height , 0.1f, 255.0f )
// We do it this way simply to avoid requiring glu.h
GLfloat zNear = 0.1f;
GLfloat zFar = 255.0f;
GLfloat aspect = float(width)/float(height);
GLfloat fH = tan( float(fieldOfView / 360.0f * 3.14159f) ) * zNear;
GLfloat fW = fH * aspect;
glFrustum( -fW, fW, -fH, fH, zNear, zFar );
```

Comment: Except glFrustum() was deprecated in 3.1 also.

Comment: why do you divide the fieldOfView by 2.0f in gluPerspective. It is specified in the specs that you should use the full fov...

Comment: @genpfault Yes, modern OpenGL requires you to deal in _matrices_ for transformation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of Dan's function, with simplified calculations from [Unspecified Behavior](http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/calculating-the-gluperspective-matrix-and-other-opengl-matrix-maths/).

```
void buildPerspProjMat(GLfloat *m, GLfloat fov, GLfloat aspect,
GLfloat znear, GLfloat zfar){

  GLfloat h = tan(fov);
  GLfloat w = h / aspect;
  GLfloat depth = znear - zfar;
  GLfloat q = (zfar + znear) / depth;
  GLfloat qn = 2 * zfar * znear / depth;

  m[0]  = w;  m[1]  = 0;  m[2]  = 0;  m[3]  = 0;

  m[4]  = 0;  m[5]  = h;  m[6]  = 0;  m[7]  = 0;

  m[8]  = 0;  m[9]  = 0;  m[10] = q;  m[11] = -1;

  m[12] = 0;  m[13] = 0;  m[14] = qn;  m[15] = 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the bit where f (h in your code) = 1/tan(fovy/2) which is mentioned on the link you provide.

Comment: Also, tan needs to be performed on radians, not degrees. Now the results match that of Dan's and my own code.

Answer (score -1):

The formula for various perspective matrices is documented in [the Direct3D documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172972%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Here is the formulation for [`D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovRH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205351%28VS.85%29.aspx), the right-handed perspective projection matrix:

```
yScale = cot(fovY/2)
xScale = yScale / aspect ratio

xScale     0          0              0
0        yScale       0              0
0        0        zf/(zn-zf)        -1
0        0        zn*zf/(zn-zf)      0
```