# glutInitContextVersion

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm having some trouble with freeglut's "glutInitContextVersion" function.
When I'm using 3, 1 as parameters, my geometry is drawn. However when I use 3,3 (which is the highest version of OpenGL my graphics card is supporting) no geometry is drawn.
What does that mean? Am I using a function that is deprecated in lower versions of OpenGL?
I'm also combining it with a call to "glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);", but since this is working without setting the context version at all, I doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: this is really hard to say with just the information you present. when you the use compatibility profile, is anything drawn? do you get any OpenGL errors? how does your rendering code look? etc.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to encounter the same problem with my code. I found that maybe it is because the glPerspective() function is no longer supported in the later version of OpenGL. You may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417697/gluperspective-was-removed-in-opengl-3-1-any-replacements) to figure out how to compute the perspective matrix.