# OpenGL why I got three different projection matrices from same parameters

Tags: opengl, matrix

my question is why I got three different matrices, and what is the difference, which is the correct one for converting coordinates from clip to eye space.

Details:

I am trying to get projection matrix of OpenGL to implement a virtual scanner, I use this matrix to convert coordinates from clip to eye space.
I found three ways to get it:

1. glGetFloatv (GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection_tmp);
2. glm::mat4 Proj = glm::perspective(
     fov,
     aspect,
     zNear, zFar);
3. compute it manually through the method given by this page: [gluperspective source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417697/gluperspective-was-removed-in-opengl-3-1-any-replacements)

Parameters passed to these three method follows:

```
const double zNear = 1;
const double zFar = 10001;//for computational convenience
const double fov = _model.getCamera().getFieldOfViewAngle();//60
//w(523)h(489) 
const double aspect = static_cast<double>(w) / static_cast<double>(h);
```

Then I get three different matrices:

glGetFloatv:

```
1.61945       0       0       0
      0 1.73205       0       0
      0       0 -1.0002      -1
      0       0 -2.0002       0
```

GLM:

```
-0.145971         0         0         0
        0  -0.15612         0         0
        0         0   -1.0002        -1
        0         0   -2.0002         0
```

Manual:

```
0.504724        0        0        0
       0  0.57735        0        0
       0        0  -1.0002        1
       0        0  -2.0002        0
```

Thanks!

Comment: `glGetFloatv` returns the current projection matrix. But how did you set it up?

Comment: @ybungalobill  I have render a model by opengl , the matrix seems be set by gluperspective I called in rendering process with qt opengl. I googled it, and many people said it is deprecated scene OpenGL3.0, so why it is worked in my 4.4 version environment? I am new to OpenGL, this really confuse me>_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `glGetFloatv` version is the only correct one among the three.

The GLM version expects the angle to be in radians, so you should correct the `fovy` by a factor of `tau/360`.

The third version is not exactly the one from the linked answer. The code in the linked answer writes **negative** one to `m[11]` whereas you posted a **positive** one. Let's assume that it's a typo and look at the other numbers. Here that code is simply wrong: it multiplies by `tan(fov/2)` instead of dividing by it. This is why it gets `0.57735 = 1/1.73205`.

I don't know why people have trouble implementing it. Just take the formula from the [`gluPerspective` specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) and write it in code:

```
void gluPerspectivInRadians(double m[16],
    double fovy, double aspect, double zNear, double zFar)
{
    double f = 1/tan(fovy/2);
    m[0] = f/aspect; m[1] = 0; m[2] = 0; m[3] = 0;
    m[4] = 0; m[5] = f; m[6] = 0; m[7] = 0;
    m[8] = 0; m[9] = 0; m[10] = (zFar+zNear)/(zNear-zFar); m[11] = -1;
    m[12] = 0; m[13] = 0; m[14] = 2*zFar*zNear/(zNear-zFar); m[15] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer! I have got these three matrices identical. Another question : Which matrix or matrix manipulation is deprecated ? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202456/how-do-you-get-the-modelview-and-projection-matrices-in-opengl) .Could you please take some time explain the first answer of this page?

Comment: @YanmingJIA: it four words: don't use legacy OpenGL.